# How do I approach this question about linear algebra (vector/scalar addition/multiplication)??

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

[image: Exercise Question Photo]

Hi this is some exercise questions my teacher recommended we do and I'm having trouble approaching these questions. Any explanation/work process would be very helpful! Thank you!!

Comment: Please take the time to post your question as text instead of an image. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the linearity of the dot product to show that

if $u\cdot v=0$ and $u\cdot w=0$ than $u \cdot(v+w)=0$ and $u\cdot (kv)=0$

Comment: thx for the hint! u⋅v = 0 is already given so how do I prove that? same with u⋅w = 0?

because i know that  u(v + w) = uv + uw -- so how am I sure that it equals 0?